# Reduce html to n characters while keeping the formatting

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Almost every language has a built-in function that can split a string at a given position. However, as soon as you have html tags in the string, the built-in function will not work properly.

Your task is to write a program or function which splits a string at the nth character but does not count characters of html tags and will output a valid html. The program must keep the formatting. Spaces outside the html tags may be counted or not counted, as you wish, but must be preserved. You can, however, exchange multiple consecutive spaces into a single space.

Input:

1. the string
2. the position to split at (0-based)

These can be taken as program or function arguments or can be read from the standard input.

Output: 
The split string which can be returned or written to the standard output.

The input will be valid html, it won't contain any entities (such as `&nbsp;`). Tags that are opened after the character limit should be omitted from the output (see the last example).

Example:

Input: `<i>test</i>`, 3
Output: `<i>tes</i>`

Input: `<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">complicated</span></strong>`, 7
Output: `<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">co</span></strong>`

Input: `no html`, 2
Output: `no`

Input: `<b>no</b> <i>html root</i>`, 5
Output: `<b>no</b> <i>ht</i>`

Input: `<b>no img</b><img src="test.png" />more text`, 6
Output: `<b>no img</b>`

You can use any language and the standard library of the given language. This is code golf, shortest program wins. Have fun!

Comment: can the input contain "<"s and ">"s that are not part of a HTML tag?

Comment: One should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<>`, so no (`&lt;` or `&gt;` won't be present either).

Comment: Could you include an example where there is mark up *after* the text node where the split occurs? Like `<i>ab</i><b>cd</b> 1`?

Comment: Are there any other options than `<i>a</i>` ?

Comment: @DavidFrank `<i>a</i><b></b>` (Which makes sense if you consider that `b` could also be `div` or `img`.)

Comment: @m.buettner You are right, I updated the rules.

Comment: The last rule is really challenging - try this : `<strong><i>even</i> <span style="color: red">more <b>difficult</b></span></strong>`

Comment: We need to have a regex answer to celebrate TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is no longer valid with the latest rule.**

## Javascript (*ES6*) <strike>94</strike> 91

```javascript
f=(s,l)=>s.split(/(<[^>]+>)/).map(x=>x[0]=='<'?x:[l-->0?y:''for(y of x)].join('')).join('')
```

```
f('<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">complicated</span></strong>', 7);
// '<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">co</span></strong>'
```

Ungolfed:

```javascript
f=(s,l)=>
    s.split(/(<[^>]+>)/). // split string s by <*>, capture group is spliced into the array 
    map(x=> // map function to every item in the array
        x[0]=='<'? // if first character is a <
            x // don't modify the string
        : // else
            [ // array comprehension
                for(y of x) // for every character y in x
                    l-->0? // if l > 0 (and decrement l)
                        y // character y
                    : // else
                        '' // empty string 
            ].join('') // join characters in array
        ).
    join('') // join all strings in array
```

Comment: Could you please provide the un-golfed code, or maybe just explanation of what and why the code does? Its currently a bit hard to grasp. Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon added ungolfed code with comments

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol - 252 chars

```
c: complement charset"<>"f: func[s n][t: e: 0 to-string collect[parse s[any[(m: 0)copy w[["</"some c">"](-- t)|["<"some c"/>"]|["<"some c">"](++ t)| any c(m: 1)](if e = 0[if m = 1[w: copy/part w n n: n - length? w]keep w]if all[n <= 0 t = 0][e: 1])]]]]
```

Ungolfed with comments:

```
c: complement charset "<>"

f: func [s n] [
    t: e: 0             ;; tag level (nesting) & end output flag
    to-string collect [
        parse s [
            any [
                (m: 0)                            ;; tag mode
                copy w [
                      ["</" some c ">" ] (-- t)   ;; close tag
                    | ["<"  some c "/>"]          ;; self-closing / void elements
                    | ["<"  some c ">" ] (++ t)   ;; open tag
                    | any c (m: 1)                ;; text mode
                ] (
                    ;; flag not set so can still output
                    if e = 0 [
                        ;; in text mode - so trim text
                        if m = 1 [
                            w: copy/part w n
                            n: n - length? w
                        ]
                        keep w
                    ]

                    ; if all trimmed and returned to flat tag level then end future output
                    if all [n <= 0  t = 0] [e: 1]
                )
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Examples in Rebol console:

```
>> f "<i>test</i>" 3
== "<i>tes</i>"

>> f {<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">complicated</span></strong>} 7
== {<strong><i>more</i> <span style="color: red">co</span></strong>}

>> f {no html} 2
== "no"

>> f {<b>no</b> <i>html root</i>} 5
== "<b>no</b> <i>ht</i>"

>> f {<b>no img</b><img src="test.png" />more text} 6
== "<b>no img</b>"

>> f {<i>a</i><b></b>} 1
== "<i>a</i>"

>> f {<strong><i>even</i> <span style="color: red">more <b>difficult</b></span></strong>} 14
== {<strong><i>even</i> <span style="color: red">more <b>diff</b></span></strong>}

>> f {<strong><i>even</i> <span style="color: red">more <b>difficult</b></span></strong>} 3 
== {<strong><i>eve</i><span style="color: red"><b></b></span></strong>}
```

Comment: Again this breaks the last rule: tags that are opened after the character limit should be omitted from the output (see the last example). In the last example the span and b tags should be omitted. This rule makes the challenge almost impossible.

Comment: @edc65 - Unfortunately (@David Frank) hasn't commented or updated his examples so its unclear whether he wants this behaviour or not?   I was hoping my last example would stir something! Going to leave as is until we get clarification.   Anyway it would only take an additional 17 chars to make it work the way you've suggested.  I didn't particular like the hack so instead rewrote it here (ungolfed) - https://gist.github.com/draegtun/93682f5a07c40bd86e31

Answer (score 0):

**(IE) JS - 135**

<strike>`function f(t,n){b=document.body;b.innerHTML=t;r=b.createTextRange();r.moveStart("character",n);r.select();r.execCommand('cut');return b.innerHTML}`</strike>

Now I feel dirty. But need to start removing all those chars...

```
function f(t,n)
{b=document.body;b.innerHTML=t;r=b.createTextRange();r.collapse();r.moveEnd("character",n);
r.select();return r.htmlText}
```

Disclaimer:

- run in IE console

Comment: This break the last (mad) rule: Tags that are opened after the character limit should be omitted from the output (try my example in comments above).

Comment: @edc65 hopefully, updated version checks on all rules

Answer (score 0):

Ruby... Very unrubylike with loops

```
def split(str,n)

  i = current = 0 
  return_str = ""

  while i < n
    if str[current] == "<"
      while str[current] != ">"
        return_str.concat str[current]
        current += 1
      end
      return_str.concat str[current]
      current += 1
    else
      return_str.concat str[current]
      i += 1
      current += 1
    end
  end

  while current < str.length
    if str[current] == "<"
      while str[current] != ">"
        return_str.concat str[current]
        current += 1
      end
      return_str.concat str[current]
      current += 1
    end
    current += 1
  end


  return_str + str[current..-1]
end
```

Comment: This question is marked as codegolf, you should golf your reply. You can start by replacing the variable names to one letter names, using shorter function names and removing white-space wherever you can